# Pointer to struct in C# to create a linked list

Tags: c#, pointers, struct, linked-list

C# does not like pointers, but I need to use them now to create a linked list, like we would do in C. The struct is simple:

```
    public unsafe struct Livro
    {
        public string name;
        public Livro* next;
    }
```

But I get the error: "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type". Any ideas?

Comment: why not [`List<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) ?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Or `LinkedList<T>` if you want a linked list ;)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit If you want to insert/remove from the middle, and don't need access by index, it's much nicer in many cases.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit `List<T>` is backed by Array. `LinkedList<T>` is truly double-linked list.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use a `class` instead of a `struct`:

```
public class Livro
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Livro Next { get; set; }
}
```

This will provide the proper behavior automatically.

That being said, you might want to just use the [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) class from the framework directly.

Comment: You are right. I did the same with classes, but the teacher wants pointers

Comment: Pointers in C# is not a very good idea. Are you sure he want's you to do this in C# and not C/C++?

Comment: It's C#. They are learning how to use pointers. That's why I can't use a collection or objects

Comment: @user2383078: One should *very rarely* use pointers for anything in C#.  Unless one needs to build a linked-list data structure in memory that will be used by code written in an unmanaged language like C, one should use object references rather than pointers.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the **string** declaration.  You have to go low level and use char* pointers.  Using `unsafe` comes with all the headaches of leaving the *managed* world...

Comment: I think that solves the problem. Now I am going to try to work with char pointers

Comment: @user2383078 - either go back to C/C++ or learn to do it the C# way. char pointers will make an already bad solution even worse.

Comment: Agreed.  Earlier he stated, "It's C# ... but the teacher wants pointers".  That teacher should be applauded for teaching pointers, but fired for using the wrong tools to do it with.  He'll leave behind a bunch of students who barely understand pointers, but think it's fine to mark blocks as `unsafe` so they can low level with pointers and do things more "efficiently".

Answer (score -1):

you can do it with struct like this:

```
struct LinkedList
{
    public int data;
    public LinkedListPtr next;
    public class LinkedListPtr
    {
        public LinkedList list;
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
struct LinkedList
{
    public int data;
    public LinkedList[] next;
}
```

but it's better to just use `class` for the linked list instead.