# Linked list implementation in C# which can be read by a C program

Tags: c#, class, pointers

I need to create a linked list in C# to pass to a utility written in C. I need to pass the address(HEAD) of this linked list to a utility written in C, which will serialize these data to send through network socket. I found linked list implementations in C# are done via class instead of structures. As in this [c-sharpcorner.com](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/linked-list-implementation-in-c-sharp/) tutorial which implemented linked list with Class.

I seen this [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551182/pointer-to-struct-in-c-sharp-to-create-a-linked-list?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) answer by *Reed Copsey* to use Class instead of structures.
In this answer,

> ```
> public unsafe struct Livro
> {
>     public string name;
>     public Livro* next;
> }
> ```
>
> is changed to
>
> ```
>  public class Livro
>  {
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public Livro Next { get; set; } 
>  }
> ```

**These are my question,**

1)If I use class instead of structure and create a linked list, will it be created in the memory in the same way as created with the structure. In another words If I create a linked list with Class, can a C program(Using structure with identical fields) read that from memory?

2)If not, what is the method to implement this? 
This is the code I implemented, but getting error

> **Error**: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a
>   managed type

```
unsafe public struct DbNode
{
    public ushort handle;                    
    public ushort perm;                      
    public ushort flags;                                         
    public ushort size_value;                
    public byte *value;                      
    public DbNode *next;                
};
```

how to fix this error?

Comment: *can a C program(Using structure with identical fields) read that from memory* fundamentally you are asking for a `data serializaton`.. it is not a good idea to share memory between two different executables on most cases..

Comment: You did not post a snippet that produces that error message.  A linked-list is not going to fly, C# objects need to be pinned before C code can use it and you can't reasonably pin an entire list.  You'll need a DbNode[], an array.  Or write interop code in a C++/CLI class library project.